# stacking DIVs one below another vertically

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv" />
    <div id="maindiv" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topdiv {   
    height: 25%;   
    width:100%;  
    border:dashed;
}

#maindiv {  
    height: 75%;    
    width:100%;     
    border:solid;
}
```

Unable to stack DIVs (topdiv, maindiv) vertically one below the other.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding 'align:left' to the css?

Comment: When you use a percentage for width/height, it's based on the parent element (width/height), which you didn't define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is really basic thing, you are self closing the `div` element tags, thus it renders incorrectly.

Correct Syntax

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv"></div>
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
</div>
```

You cannot self close the `div` tags

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QyBpy/)

[image]

[Click here](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML documents

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Can't have self closing div's. I havn't woke up fully yet :P

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/QVPA3/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv"></div>       
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv"> </div>
    <div id="maindiv"> </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
    #topdiv {
        height: 25%;
        width:100%;
        border:dashed;
    }

    #maindiv {
        height: 75%;
        width:100%;     
        border:solid;
    }
```

**You must close the div tags**

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use a percentage for width/height, it's based on the parent element (width/height), which you didn't define.
Second, `div` is not a self-closing tag.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv"></div>
    <div id="maindiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}

#topdiv {   
    height: 25%;   
    width:100%;  
    border:dashed;
}

#maindiv {  
    height: 75%;    
    width:100%;     
    border:solid;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QJC8x/

Answer (score 0):

If you will not close div tag, next div start from same point of first div
Close Div tag

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topdiv"> </div>
    <div id="maindiv"> </div>
</div>
```